# Matlab: Creating duplicate edges in graph

Tags: matlab, graph

I want to have duplicate edges or even more edges if required, between to vertices.

The normal graph command does not allow and gives error that duplicate edges are not allowed, same thing happens for digraph as well.

Does anyone know of any way or trick to do this?

Let's say as an example I want matlab to draw below graph:

```
G = graph([1 1 3],[2 2 5])
plot(G)
```

Comment: How would you know between which edges to draw a vertex if you have duplicate edges?

Comment: @patrik probably you mean between which vertices to draw edges :) does it matter? I just want to show to curved edge connecting vertex 1 to vertex 2 for example in graph above.

Comment: Well the problem is that if you do not know which edge you want to draw from it would make sence to choose the first. This would still only fill one of the edges and make duplicates unusable. Maybe the problem is that you want to have many vertices between 2 edges? Are you sure that you is not really looking for plotting an array or want to change the weights of the vertices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the MATLAB class graph. Graphs that allow multiple edges between two nodes are typically called multi-graphs or similar, and are less commonly used.

You could work around this by adding a Weight variable that is larger if it represents several edges:

```
G = graph([1 3], [2 5], [2 1]);
```

This could then be used to plot the edge with a thicker line:

```
plot(G, 'LineWidth', G.Edges.Weight);
```

Other workarounds may be possible, depending on what you want to do with this graph.